# IBM DB2 Workgroup server edition Missing DB2CC (Need help for understanding of DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to self learning on installing and configuring on `DB2` and so I've downloaded and installed from http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2workgroup-edition/ (Free Trial version)

After following the installation wizard, I've installed "successfully" (I guess) The DB2 has started (indicated by the notification are icon at bottom right) but I couldn't start `db2 control center`? I tried the command `db2 list database directory` but it's throwing error `SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.  SQLSTATE=58031`

May I know what are the possible problems?

I'm installing on `window7 64bits`

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded the DB2 profile. You probably have to change the user to the one specified in the installation, normally db2admin.

Since there, you can use the database as sysadm.

BTW, you triel does not have control center, it was removed from DB2 long time ago.

Also, this question is not for stack over flow, but for databases